# Struggling to find solution: question 5 (ODE) (Separable Equations) (Polynomials)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials

Could someone help me with this problem?
$$y'=\frac{x^3+x^2y+3y^3}{x^3+3xy^2}$$

---

I have tried $y=ux$ since it kind of resembles $f(\frac{y}{x})$ structure, and tried to gather terms in parentheses to resolve it but couldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRICK: Divide both numerator and denominator by $x^3$, so your EDO would be $$y'=\frac{1+(y/x)+3(y/x)^3}{1+2(y/x)^2}$$ and with your substitution $$u'x+u=\frac{1+u+3u^3}{1+3u^2}$$